# How is the absolute value on a product space defined?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, product-space

I want to show that a map from the cantor set $C$ to its product $C\times C$ is homeomorphic, and I am stuck at continuity because in the epsilon delta proof I am not sure how to deal with the absolute values in the range.

How is the absolute value $|(x,y)|$ defined if $(x,y)$ is an element of a product space, say $[0,1]$x$[0,1]$?

Should I treat this like a vector and just take a Euclidean distance? My topology background is very limited, thanks.

Comment: You can use the Euclidean distance. Most standard distances are fine - $|x|+|y|$ works, as does $\max(|x|,|y|)$. Turns out, continuity is the same for all of these metrics - that is, a function which is continuous with one of these metrics is continuous with any of the others.